# ImageMagick PHP wrong width

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm having issue regarding rectangle width and strokes. Somehow, the width is wrong. Please se the example below.

```
$canvas = new Imagick;
$canvas->newImage(600, 600, "black", "jpg");

$rectangle = new ImagickDraw;
$rectangle->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel("red"));
$rectangle->setStrokeWidth(0);
$rectangle->rectangle(0, 0, 599, 598);
$canvas->drawImage($rectangle);
```

The example should produce an image (600x600) with a rectangle filling almost the whole canvas. There should be one pixel on the right side revealing the black background and two pixels in the bottom of the image revealing the black background. Everything else should be red (the rectangle). However, this is not the image produced.

[image]

As you can see, the black background is only revealed in the bottom. Looks like everything is off by one?

Comment: From 0 to 599 there are exactly 600 pixels. The pixel "zero" also counts.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that. Feels a bit wrong since the 3rd and 4th argument in ->rectangle() is width and height. I would assume it took the "zero" pixel into account

Comment: Ahh, it actually not width and height but x2 and y2. My mistake

Comment: It's pretty much like everything related to arrays and indexing in programming. For example the array length may be 10 but the first index is 0 and the last index is 9. Same here - the total amount of pixels is 600 but the first pixel is 0 and the last one is 599.